# Distribute iOS app to my client iOS Developer Account

Tags: ios, app-store, software-distribution

I developed an iOS app for my client and I have to find a way to distribute (me or them) the app on client's app store without them have to give me their account credentials. Can I do this? How should I sign .ipa file?

P.S.: I have read many posts on this topic on stackoverflow, but no one has clarified my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Even if they don't have an Enterprise account, they can add you as a user on their account. They need to login to developer.apple.com, then click on the **People** tab. They need to add you there. [Here is some good docs on what I just described.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/MemberCenter_Recipes/AddingTeamAdminsandMembers/AddingTeamAdminsandMembers.html)

They will also need to add you to the iTunesConnect account. Unfortunately, for some reason Apple doesn't allow you to have the same email address linked to multiple accounts, so the client will need to add you iTunesConnect account, but make sure whichever email they add isn't linked to another account. [This is another doc on what I just described](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/iTunesConnect_Recipes/Articles/ManageTeam.html)

Once that is setup, you'll have access to the account, but you'll never see their credentials, and they can remove you whenever.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful answer. My client has to give me his distribution certificate private key, so that I am able to load the app on client's store?

Comment: AFAIK, you'll need to generate your own distribute key, but you can upload it to their account once they give you access (I think you'll need admin access to do that).

Comment: Can I have two valid distribution certificates at the same time?

Comment: @Giorgio Yes, you can have multiple certificates at the same time

Comment: Thanks @workInAFishBowl. I read that a **Team Admin** is not able to submit apps to the store, but only the **Team Agent** can do that.What about Application Loader? If I give to my client an .ipa signed with a my provisioning profile (for example an Ad Hoc provisioning profile), he can re-sign it with his app store provisioning profile via Application Loader? Sorry, but I'm very confused.

Comment: @Giorgio I'm not sure. I'm an admin on a client's account, and have submitted an app multiple times

Comment: I read it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH16-SW14

Answer (score 0):

If they have an Enterprise account, they should be able to add you to their account (with your own credentials) and give you permission to upload/distribute the app.

If they have a single user account, then they would need to upload it.

Comment: thanks for reply. As workInAFishBowl said, even with a single user account, you can add an user on your account.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out http://www.testflightapp.com  Its a great website (free) for doing beta builds and development and distribution.  We use it at work frequently.